# How to dispatch clicked URLs to specific browser based on domain (as OSX Choosy does)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I am trying to replicate the functionality of Choosy (https://www.choosyosx.com/) under Ubuntu 16.04.

In particular, I want to have it set up so that when I click in a non-browser application on a link to github.com, pivotaltracker.com, or youtube.com that URL opens in Chrome, and all other URLs open in Firefox.

I'm fine with links in browsers staying in the same browser.

Is there any easy way to do what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

I liked the idea and didn't find any existing solution quickly so I've written my own dispatcher: https://github.com/int-ua/openbydomain/

The idea is to make it your default "browser".

P.S. My first use-case will be [apport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1876987).

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) Firefox addon. I think it has the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Thank you for your link. Unfortunately, it wouldn't work for me because of two reasons. 1. AFAIU it just allows switching browser _after_ opening a link in Firefox. It's useless with `apport`, for example, because of redirections (see the link in my answer for details). 2. Firefox is the browser where I'm authenticated to services and I don't have it as default for opening links as a precaution.